# How to return a value from Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I have a Fancybox that opens up another aspx.page which loads a DropDownList into the fancybox. Then I need the user to select a value from the list. I wanted to know if it is possible to return that selected value to the page I called the fancybox from.

Ex: I'm on website/test1.aspx.  Test1.aspx calles a fancybox that loads Test2.aspx in the fancybox. Test2.aspx has the ddl, the user selects a value from the ddl, then fancybox closes and returns the selected value back to Test1.aspx

Here is my fancybox:

```
$.fancybox({
                'autoScale': false,
                'type': 'iframe',
                'height': 800,
                'width': 800,
                'href': 'Utilities/MoveFileTemplate.aspx?ExpenseID=' + $(this).children(':first').html(),
                onComplete: function () {
                    $('#fancybox-overlay').unbind();
                }
            });
```

In MovingFileTemplate.aspx I have a hidden field that gets assigned the selected value from the DropDownList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in fancybox iframed page:

```
window.top.DoSomethingWithValue($('#myddl').val());
```

Code in top (opener) page:

```
function DoSomethingWithValue(val)
{
    alert(val);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do they both go in the page that calls the other form. Or does one go in the page that is calling and the other in the page that is being called?

Comment: The `window.top...` snippet goes in the sub page. The function goes in the parent page.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but in my sub Page it says there is no such function window.top."DoSomethingWith". I kept the name the same to first test it

Comment: @user1084319 If you have more than one nested iframe, use `window.opener` instead of `window.top`.